# Creating a custom auth provider and using custom auth tokens in Swift for Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use a custom auth provider in Swift so my users can login with a username and password. However, I tried following this tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) and it says I need to add support for custom auth tokens. I'm not able to follow this tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). Could someone help me through the process?

Comment: Without seeing what you've tried and where you got stuck, it's unlikely that anyone can write a better instruction than the documentation you linked or some of the existing [tutorials out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+create+custom+auth+provider).